# Etcher AppImage won't open on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, etcher

I downloaded [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) in an attempt to install RetroPie.  After unzipping, it gives me an AppImage, which I'm supposed to be able to run from anywhere.  I changed the permissions

```
$ chmod a+x balena-etcher-electron-1.4.9-i386.AppImage
```

Then tried to run it from the command line.  No good.

```
$ ./balena-etcher-electron-1.4.9-i386.AppImage 
./balena-etcher-electron-1.4.9-i386.AppImage: error while loading shared libraries: libfuse.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Another search found a GitHub error for Etcher on Mint: https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/issues/1490

In that thread, it suggests to download the balena-etcher-electron_1.4.9_i386.deb from the [release page](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases).  I used the one from [v1.4.9](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/releases/tag/v1.4.9).

Installed that and everything seems to be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really still on a 32-bit machine? If not, then you should use the 64-bit AppImage. And be aware of https://github.com/balena-io/etcher/issues/1305